# How do I pass payload to selector? react + redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, selector, getter

What I want to have is a parameterized getter. Lets say I have module in redux users and every user has ID, I want by passing id return this user. My main issue is how do I pass *id* from component itself to mapStateToProps ?

Here is component:

```
const Main = (props) => {
    console.log(props.userNameById(3)) // that's what I want pass an ID and get user
    return <div>Hello</div>
}
// that's what I googled that inside props you should receive parameter, but how do I pass it ?

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => { 
    console.log(props) // empty object
    return {
         userNameById: getName(state, props)
     }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Main)
```

And then my rootReducer (I know it's not important for a question, but just in case):

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { createSelector  } from "reselect";
import usersReducer, * as fromUsers from "./users/usersReducers";
import alertReducer from "./alerts/alertsReducers";


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    users: usersReducer,
    alerts: alertReducer,
})

export const getName = (state, id) => return id; // let's just simplify a code, the main question how do I pass id

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` is supposed to return a piece of state rather than a function that extracts the state.

if you wants to extract your state inside your component you could return users than at component find by some value:

```
const Main = (props) => {
  console.log(props.users.find(user => user.id === 3))
  console.log(getName(props.users, 3)) // or if you want to use some helper function directly
  return <div>Hello</div>
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ users }) => ({ users })
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Main)
```

but if you expect to receive id from props you could alternatively use `id` props at your mapStateToProps:

```
const Main = (props) => {
  console.log(props.user)
  return <div>Hello</div>
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ users }, { id }) => ({ user: users.find(user => user.id === id) })
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Main)
```

Comment: I see, thank you! that answers my question!